# How to delete words that longer than a certain length in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, tokenize

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
myList = [
    {
        'id':1,
        'text':['I like cheese.', 
                'I love cheese.', 'oh Ilikecheese !'],
        'text_2': [('david',
    'david',
    'I do not like cheese.'),
   ('david',
    'david',
    'cheese is good.')]    
    },
    {
        'id':2,
        'text':['I like strawberry.', 'I love strawberry'],
        'text_2':[('alice',
    'alice',
    'strawberry is good.'),
   ('alice',
    'alice',
    ' strawberry is so so.')]    
    }
]
```

I want to delete the words that longer than a certain number of letters (e.g. 9 letters).

The ideal output is the same list of dictionaries but delete the misspelled words such as removing "Ilikecheese":

```
myList = [
    {
        'id':1,
        'text':['I like cheese.', 
                'I love cheese.', 'oh!'],
        'text_2': [('david',
    'david',
    'I do not like cheese.'),
   ('david',
    'david',
    'cheese is good.')]    
    },
    {
        'id':2,
        'text':['I like strawberry.', 'I love strawberry'],
        'text_2':[('alice',
    'alice',
    'strawberry is good.'),
   ('alice',
    'alice',
    ' strawberry is so so.')]    
    }
]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Make a list comprehension that omits the words you don't want.  `newtext = [word for word in text if len(word) <= 9]`

Comment: @j1-lee thanks for the suggestions, I modified the question

Comment: What exactly is preventing you from writing code to solve the problem, as it stands? What is your idea about how the code needs to work, and what part of it exactly are you unable to write? If you wrote code, please show the code and explain what happened when you tried it and how that is different from what is supposed to happen. Also, why is this tagged as `tokenize`? Do you not actually know how to split a string up into words?

Comment: Please read [ask] and note that [you are expected to make some attempt to solve the problem yourself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service, and ["any suggestions?" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question); you need to be much more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove each words in a string which is longer or equal than 9. Criterium for splitting a string: single white-space.

```
myList = # above

for d in myList:
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            for i, word in enumerate(v):
                v[i] = ' '.join(list(filter(lambda w: len(w)<9, word.split(' '))))

for d in myList: print(d)
```

Output

```
{'id': 1, 'text': ["I 'll tell you what . Next say ' Potts ' on the tower .", 'I assume . Light her up .', 'Cap , I need the lever !']}
{'id': 2, 'text': ['Dr. Banner .', 'Stark , we need a plan of attack !', '( taken by that )', 'Everyone ! Clear out !', "Think the guy 's a friendly ?", 'Those people need .', 'Then suit up .']}
```

If `tuple`s instead of `lists`

```
for d in myList:
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, tuple):
            v = list(v)
            for i, word in enumerate(v):               
                v[i] = ' '.join([w for w in word.split(' ') if len(w) < 9])
            d[k] = tuple(v)

for d in myList: print(d)
```

Comment: maybe more readable `v[i] = ' '.join([w for w in word.split(' ') if len(w) < 9])`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That works. However, I just noticed that I have tuple in my data. When I try your method I jot this error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'. I changed the sample data. Any suggestions for addressing this error?

Comment: just edit like this:  `if isinstance(v, tuple):` and right below  `v = list(v)` this will cast each tuple to list

Comment: ... and `d[k] = tuple(v)` right outside the scope of the loop with `enumerate` so you will update the dictionary and have back a your data as a tuple (in case)

Comment: I have both list (i.e. 'text') and tuple (i.e. 'text_2')...what should I do...?

Comment: @Alina I updated the answer with the tuple-solution. Doesn't work?

Comment: the error has been fixed but "building'sgonna" is still in the output...

Comment: by me it works. I checked it again now... Did you copy-past the code above?

Comment: my bad, it works. Thanks so much for the answer! I changed the example list to make the question more clear...